# preStop hook inside pod using K8s API

Tags: kubernetes-apiserver

Is there a way to call a function before the Pod is being terminated? preStop hook examples are based on yaml specs.

I want to use the K8s API, should I just write a SIGTERM handler ? What is the "safe" way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, checkout finalizers.

They exactly get invoked before getting terminated.

example: 
https://book.kubebuilder.io/reference/using-finalizers.html?highlight=finalizers#using-finalizers

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/ used this to solve the problem